# Why doesn't my OCR opencv in python code work at al?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

i am new to this forum so sorry if this is question is too long for this place. I just started coding and i never really had a lesson so i am searching wat i can find on the internet. I first looked at an youtube video where he tried this on python 2, so thats why it's sort of messy but i really want it to work.

```
 import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from PIL import Image

filepathinQ = "images/isomeren.jpg"
filepathinQPNG = 'images/imageinq.png'
filepathPNG = "images/atomen.png"

###First pictuce scan

class shapeRecognition():

    def __init__(self, img):
        self.img = img



    def Voorbeeldenmaker(self):

        im = Image.open('images/isomeren.png')
        image = np.array(im)



        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        max_dimension = max(image.shape)
        scale = 700/max_dimension
        image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

        lower = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
        upper = np.array([15,15,15], dtype=np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.inRange(self.img, lower, upper)
        (flags, contours, h) = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, 0,(120,0,145), 3)
        cv2.imshow("vorm", mask)


        return contours

#second picture scan


class shape2Recognition():

    def __init__(self2, img2):
        self2.img2 = img2



    def inquestion(self2):
        im = Image.open(filepathinQPNG)
        image = np.array(im)



        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        max_dimension = max(image.shape)
        scale = 700/max_dimension
        image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale)

        lower2 = np.array([0,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)
        upper2 = np.array([15,15,15], dtype=np.uint8)
        mask2 = cv2.inRange(image, lower2, upper2)
        (flags, contours2, h) = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cv2.drawContours(mask2, contours2, 4,(120,0,145), 3)
        cv2.imshow("vorm2", mask2)



        return contours2

#threshold for the second picture
#to make it in black and white

def treshold(imageArray):
        newAr = imageArray
        img = Image.open(filepathinQ)
        img = img.convert("RGBA")
        datas = img.getdata()

        newData = []
        for eachRow in newAr:
            for eachPix in eachRow:
                if ((int(eachPix[0]) + int(eachPix[1]) + int(eachPix[2]))/3) > 220:
                    newData.append((255,255,255,255))

                else:
                    newData.append((0,0,0,255))


        img.putdata(newData)
        img.save('images/imageinq.png', "PNG")


#comparing the two

def zijnzegelijk(image):

    x = 0

    while x < 21:
        cnt = contours[x]
        cnt2 = contours2[4]
        ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt, cnt2 ,1, 0.0)
        print(ret)
        print("\n")
        print(x)
        print("\n")


        x+= 1












i = Image.open(filepathinQ)
iAr = np.array(i)

treshold(iAr)


img2 = cv2.imread(filepathinQPNG)
shape2Recognition = shape2Recognition(img2)
contours2 = shape2Recognition.inquestion()


i2 = Image.open(filepathinQPNG)
iAr2 = np.array(i2)

img = cv2.imread(filepathPNG)
shapeRecognition = shapeRecognition(img)
contours = shapeRecognition.Voorbeeldenmaker()


zijnzegelijk(iAr2)
```

Comment: Try editing your question to cut down your code to the minimal amount you can to reproduce your problem - and either post the error you're getting or how your results differ from what you'd expect (it's unclear if by "doesn't work at all" you mean you're getting an error, or the wrong output)

Comment: Although right off the bat I can you you're going to have issues if that first line `import numpy as np` in your code actually does have a space in front of it. Python is sensitive to white space; get rid of that

Comment: @HFBrowning that's obviously a mistake when he was writing the code here.

Comment: @ROAR why obvious? Wouldn't it be stupid not to point it out if that is indeed what is causing his whole code to "not work at all" (whatever the heck that means)?